# Creating a subscription using bank account number using stripe js in node js

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, subscription, payment-method

I have created subscription by accespting credit/debit card number, exp month, exp year and cvc from front end angular app and creating

- Customer
- Product
- Product Price
- Payment Method
- Subscription

In payment method i provide following details:

```
    async function createPaymentMethod(data) {
  let body = {
    type: 'card',
    card: {
      number: data.card?.number,
      exp_month: data.card?.exp_month,
      exp_year: data.card?.exp_year,
      cvc: data.card?.cvc
    }
  };
  return await stripe.paymentMethods.create(body);
}
```

Now i want to create payment method but want to use customer's bank account number but i am unable to find a way to do it. I want to add "type: bank_account"

Note: I am using Strip JS and Node JS. All of this I want to do on server side i.e node js

Answer (score 0):

Collecting Credit Card server-side is a bad idea, since you will expose yourself to the burden on PCI-Compliance. You would want to review [Stripe's Integration Security Guide](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide). Generally you would want to use client-side SDK to collect credit card information instead.

To the question of a bank account, it depends on which specific PaymentMethod you're gonna use (which country's bank transfer?) Ie. If you are talking about ACH in the US, you should follow [the ACH Guide](https://stripe.com/docs/ach). Similarly it will collect bank account information client-side in exchange of a token, then passing it up to your back end.